# Pagination on a LinkedHashSet

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have an API controller which allows users return a list of user profiles they have saved to their account. This data is stored in MongoDB and in POJO terms the data I want to paginate on is a LinkedHashSet of strings.

Now, in some other parts of my code I have simple `List<String>` which I'm able to "paginate" via the code below:

```
public static <T> List<T> getPage(List<T> sourceList, int page, int pageSize) {
    if (pageSize <= 0 || page < 0) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("invalid page size: " + pageSize);
    }
    if (sourceList == null || sourceList.size() < (page * pageSize)) {
        return Collections.emptyList();
    }
    return sourceList.subList(page, Math.min(page + pageSize, sourceList.size()));
}
```

Can anyone help me do apply this same logic to a LinkedHashset? I'm struggling since the collection does not have a sublist method.

Below is my controller:

```
 @GetMapping("/users/savedlist")
public Iterable<User> getUsersListOfSavedProfiles(Authentication authentication,
                                                  @PageableDefault(page = 0, size = 10) Pageable pageable) {
    return savedProfilesService.getUsersSavedProfiles(authentication.getName(), pageable.getPageNumber(), pageable.getPageSize());
```

And the Pojo:

```
@Document(collection = "UsersSavedProfiles")
public class SavedProfiles {
    @Id
    @JsonIgnore
    private String _id;

    private String userId;

    private LinkedHashSet<String> savedProfileIds;
```

Access to the DB via DALImpl:

```
@Override
public SavedProfiles findByUserId(String userId) {
    Query query = new Query();
    query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("userId").is(userId));
    return mongoTemplate.findOne(query, SavedProfiles.class);
}
```

**** Edit for Clarity ****
I know I can paginate a Mongo query for User Profile documents BUT what I need to do is paginate the ArrayList savedProfiles inside one of the documents.

Thanks again to the people who looked at this

Comment: Idk what's possible with Mongo queries, but I think ideally you would want your DB query to include the page size + offset. Otherwise, you load all the data every time and then throw the non-paged data away. Which would also probably mean the query would return the list of `savedProfileIds` instead of the SavedProfile...

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50260384/what-is-the-best-way-for-pagination-on-mongodb-using-java

Comment: Thanks for the responses! BUT here's where I'm stumped. The object I want to paginate on isnt a document. Its an ArrayList in the document if that makes sense. From what I can see and have done before I just paginate with Mongo as the above link on Documents. For instance give me page 1 size 10 of UserProfile documents. What I want do to is get a paginated view of the list array inside one of the UserProfiles. Thank you btw